# Javascript intellisense in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, intellisense, ace-editor

**TL;DR**

I need intelligent autocompletion/intellisense for JavaScript in ACE Editor.

**Explanation**

I am creating an online IDE for JavaScript using ACE Editor. Is there any library or open-source project that allows intelligent autocompletion for JavaScript.

JavaScript is a dynamic language, intellisense integration is trivial for such languages ([TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) does support this). ACE editor only supports basic autocompletition (like Sublime Text) using `enableBasicAutocompletion`.

I need intelligent autocompletion, an engine that parses the javascript in backend in realtime and provides suggestions.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Long time ago since you asked this question, but have you looked at the monaco editor? I think this would be a perfect fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try tern extension for Ace from https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.ace/

update: a better version at https://github.com/sevin7676/Ace.Tern with a demo http://sevin7676.github.io/Ace.Tern/demo.html

Comment: Is there any alternative? Tern.ace is too clunky and hangs the browser while editing large files.

Comment: Edited answer to add a better version, I don't know of any premade alternatives that parse code and extract suggestions.

Comment: how do you trigger autocomplete without typing ctrl + space for this? like Android Studio does

Comment: @PirateApp by setting option `enableLiveAutoCompletion:true`